# MGTwitterEngine and Table View

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mgtwitterengine

I am using MGTwitterEngine for my iphone application. I instantiated a TwitterEngine object call some Twitter API function (like getting Status). The problem is: I am getting parsed dictionary object at the delegate method after some time where my table view is set already. How can I refresh the table view or how I can make sure that I have the data before table view is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

This will reload myTableView. After getting the data update your data source for the table view and send reloadData message to the table view. It will be refreshed.